# How to find a certain value in a vector of strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a program for an assignment that will add and remove strings from a vector of strings, but first I need to create a function that will find whether or not the string already exists in the vector.

I've already tried to use a loop to search through the vector to find a specific desired string at each index. I tried adding a `break;` to exit if the string was found. I don't know if the function is supposed to be void or boolean.

```
bool FindString(int vctrSize, vector<string> restaurantVctr, string targetRestnt) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < vctrSize; ++i) {
        if (restaurantVctr.at(i) == targetRestnt) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be true if the string was found, else it would obviously be false.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also received the warning: "not all control paths return a value"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: What's wrong with [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: `return false;` should be outside of the loop.

Comment: Additional suggestions: 1) Don't pass the size, as `std::vector` already knows it. 2) Pass the vector by `const &` to avoid making a copy unnecessarily. 3) Pass the string by `const &` for the same reason. 4) If you use `std::find` or `std::binary_search` (must be sorted to use that one), you don't need a separate function at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I recommend using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as others have recommended, if you're curious what is wrong with your code, the problem is your `else`:

```
for (i = 0; i < vctrSize; ++i) {
    if (restaurantVctr.at(i) == targetRestnt) {
        return true;
        break;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the first item in your vector is **not** equal to `targetRestnt`, then your function *returns*--that is, it ends execution.

You only want to return false if it's not in the whole list--that is, you want the whole loop to execute:

```
for (i = 0; i < vctrSize; ++i) {
    if (restaurantVctr.at(i) == targetRestnt) {
        return true;
        // Also, you don't need a break here: you can remove it completely
        // For now, I just commented it out
        // break;
    }
}

// We didn't find it:
return false;
```

Comment: The `break` (also present in the OP's code) is superfluous and unreachable, since the `return` will exit the function first.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't think it will cause a problem here because `return` will always execute before `break`, but I edited it out, as both of you are right: it is unneeded.

Answer (score 9):

You should use std algorithms whenever possible:

```
auto result = std::find(restaurantVctr.begin(), restaurantVctr.end(), targetRestnt);
return result != restaurantVctr.end();
```

That is exactly what [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is for.

Comment: Exactly. Also, if the vector happens to be sorted, [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) would be ideal here, with better complexity.